# android gallery image position problem

Tags: android, position, gallery

As you in following android album widget images placement is from middle of the gallery i want to start image placement from beginning of the album.

[image]

Comment: This is what you are [finding](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B2Ya1LFzrGR9MHRmaWpMX0dTOVNEMFlSQUJUX3NVZw)

Answer (score 9):

`Gallery#setSelection(1);` after the `setAdapter()` will do the trick :)

Comment: +1 because it works if you have a fixed element length gallery :). And it's a simple solution

Answer (score 2):

can you use scrollX in the gallery xml ?,the Value you should do yourself i think

Answer (score 1):

The gallery view of Android is designed to start from middle part of the activity.You cant start the image placement from start of gallery.
 To do this you can make customized gallery view with help of Image view and horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: i am using custom gallery any sample code to move image at beginning ?

Answer (score 0):

The gallery by default align the elements to center.... You should be rewrite the gallery class...

Comment: can you tell me which method to override to align it left if i rewrite gallery class ?