# how Left selector gallery android?

Tags: android, cursor, gallery, selecteditem

I have an image gallery, and the gallery has a default selector center, look at the picture

[image: gallery1]

I do not need the left space, therefore I need a left selector, as seen on the picture:

[image: gallery2]

And this is my code

```
 final  Gallery galay = (Gallery)findViewById(R.id.gallerylay);

 galay.setAdapter(new layoutAdapter(this));
galay.setSpacing(50);
  ..................

public class layoutAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context ctx;


    public layoutAdapter(Context c) {
        ctx = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return pics1.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {

        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {

        return arg0;
    }

    @Override

    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {

        // Declare Variables
        TextView txtrank;
        TextView txtcountry;
        TextView txtpopulation;
        TextView imgflag;
        View itemView = (arg1 == null) ? View.inflate(ctx, R.layout.slide, null) :arg1;

        Gallery.LayoutParams innerLP = new Gallery.LayoutParams(250, 350);

        itemView.setLayoutParams(innerLP);
        itemView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cadre1);
      txtrank=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
      txtrank.setText(pics1[arg0]);
        return itemView;
    }}
```

How can I do this, please?

Comment: have u use xml to achive this

Answer (score 0):

Have you implemented gallery view in XMl? if yes then set

```
android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
android:columnWidth="70dp"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
```

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404590/gallery-default-item-selected-is-in-center