# Android, How to stick gallery into left side of screen?

Tags: android, layout, gallery

I have two questions.

The first, when i load the activity first item of gallery is in the middle. How to ask android to align it to left? (actually i used align="left" but it seems doesn't work)

the second, my activity includes three items, header, body and footer. currently the footer (gallery) is on top of body. I want bottom of body stays on above of footer instead of behind of footer.

any suggestions appreciated. The image is like this.

[image]

the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android         = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width  = "fill_parent"
    android:layout_height = "fill_parent"
    android:background    = "@drawable/bg" >


    <!-- Loading header of this UI which is coded separately -->
    <include
        android:id="@+id/header" 
        layout="@layout/header_bar" />



    <GridView 
        android:id="@+id/news_gridview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/header"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />  


    <Gallery 
        android:id="@+id/gallery"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For 1st:**

Check this existing SO question:

- [android gallery image position problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615140/android-gallery-image-position-problem)

**For 2nd:**
 - You need to include `android:layout_above="@+id/gallery"` in your GridView.
 - Remoev `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`

In short, define:

```
<GridView 
        android:id="@+id/news_gridview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:layout_above="@+id/gallery"/>
```

Comment: Thank you Paresh. instead of using so many lines of code i preferred to use "gallery.setSelection(imAdapter.getCount()/2);" which brings gallery to the middle. But i did your suggestion for second advice but error happened and i don't know why, but i couldn't use it. Thanks again.